# Storing non-valuable data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I use Core Data to store objects in my app. Basically I store objects valuable to user, for example things that user liked or places where he wants to go. There is a hidden relationship between every of these objects and user himself. Everything is perfectly logical. But now I want to store (cache) some data that is not directly linked to user, for example result of search requests. These objects mostly are used only in one particular place and could have some expire time like cache or something like that. So I need to store these objects but be able to remove them from storage in future. The thing is that these objects are of the same entity as my valuable objects. Another thing is that there could be a relationship between these non-valuable objects and some valuable objects.

What is the best way to store such non-valuable objects and, most important, to clean Core Data Storage from them?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use you need for these items.
basically, these are items that have an expiry date (temporary objects), you could use a timestamp on each object, or you could create an new entity relating to the items (one-to-one relationship) that you can query and delete by under conditions you specify.
When you open the store coordinator, you could have a cleanup rule (that you will need to implement) it will run in the background and remove items that are no longer relevant (make sure not to display them to the user, or access them when you perform the cleanup).
try to keep your cleanup in the background and perform it at times which will not disturbe the user.
in my own opinion, it is better to mark the items as hidden, then deleting them immediately as deletion is a heavy operation that might block the UI. also try and keep your deletions small (not all objects at once, but small batches of objects)